# google map will not be open on Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a live site created on dnn. I enterd site url on firefox and site will be opened after that i click on contact_Us tab a box will be open where multiple country names and "Get Directions" button placed on the box when i click on country name like "New-York" and click on "Get Directions" a map will be opened and it will point out a location on the map. It also working on google chrome. But the map will not be open on internet explorer. Why?
Kindly suggest me.
Waiting for reply.
Thanks

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Google map is not visible on Internet Explorer but its working fine on mozilla firefox and google chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open google map on IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487038/how-to-open-google-map-on-ie9)

Answer (score 1):

**Add Google Maps as a trusted site**

The easiest and safest way to enable viewing maps in your browser is to add Google Maps to your list of trusted sites in Internet Explorer. Here's how:

Click Tools > Internet Options.
Click the Security tab.
Select the "Trusted sites" icon, and click the Sites button. Deselect the option "Require server verification for all sites in this zone."
In the text field Add this Web site to the zone, type "maps.google.com" (without quotes) and click Add.
Repeat step five to add the following sites: "local.google.com", "www.google.com", and "*.google.com" (all without quotes).
Click OK, then click OK again to save your changes.

**Clear the browser cache**

Clearing your browser cache may resolve the problem you're experiencing.

To clear your cache in Internet Explorer 8.0+, follow these steps:

In Internet Explorer, click Tools. If you don't see the menu, press Alt on your keyboard to show menus.
Select Delete Browsing History.
Select the checkbox next to "Temporary Internet Files."
Click Delete.
It can take several minutes for the cache history to be deleted. Once the files have been deleted, click Okay.
For lower versions of IE, see our article on clearing your browser’s cache.

**Make sure JavaScript, ActiveX, and "binary behaviors" are enabled**

JavaScript and ActiveX are what help to make your Google Maps experience more dynamic and interactive. If not enabled, certain functions built into the product won’t work properly.

**To enable these browser settings in IE:**

Click Tools > Internet Options.
Click the Security tab.
Click the Custom level button.
Verify that the Enable button next to "Run ActiveX controls and plug-in" is selected. If you're using Windows XP, verify that the Enable button next to "Binary and script behaviors" is selected.
Verify that the Enable button under "Active scripting" is selected.
Click OK, then click OK again to save your changes.

**Update the "scripting engine" of your system**

Google Maps takes advantage of several advanced browser features. If your browser appears not to load the map properly, you may need to update your scripting engine. You can obtain the latest scripting engine directly from Microsoft:

For Windows 7, Vista, XP, and 2000:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/default.aspx

You'll probably need to restart your system after performing this update. Then, try Maps again to confirm if this step resolved your problem.

**Install the latest version of DirectX and Flash Player**

Some IE users have reported that installing the latest version (9.0c) of DirectX has resolved the difficulties they've experienced viewing maps. To install DirectX, please visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113

In order for certain functions of Google Maps to work (such as Street View), you need to have the latest version of Adobe Flash Player installed. To install Flash, please visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

**Check for security settings or browser plug-ins**

Some security programs and third-party browser plug-ins are designed to modify webpage content and may interfere with Google Maps. If applicable, try adding maps.google.com as a trusted site for your security program's firewall.

Please refer the site: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/21849?hl=en

Comment: I followed all the above steps. But its not working.

Comment: Here is the jquery code under the "Get Direction" button.                                                              $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#new-yorkiframeNav').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.vcard').hide();      
        $('#new-yorkiframe').slideToggle("slow");         
        return false;
      });
and here is the css code :

Comment: And the country selection is "New-york" and "New -york" div start from here <div id="new-yorkiframe" class="tab-pane vcard" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(5, 72, 65); width: 950px; border: 10px solid rgb(5, 72, 65); display: block;">

    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q &source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=+40+Wall+Street,+11th+Floor+New+York,+NY+10005&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=39.320439,86.572266&t=m &ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=40+Wall+St,+New+York,+10005&iwloc=A&output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 100%; height:379px;">

Comment: #document
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html class="no-maps-mini" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"> and "New-york" div end here:
                <head> … </head>
                <body class="kui small" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope=""> … </body>
            </html>
    </iframe>

</div>